# Connected component of the distinguished point in a Fort space.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $M$ be a countable set and $p\in M$ what we'll call the distinguished point, define the **Fort topology** as follows: A set $U$ is open iff its complement is finite or it contains $p$.

This makes the set a metric, totally separable, compact space.

By definition it is clear that the connected component of a point $x\neq p$ is $C_x=\{x\}$ since $\{x\}$ is open, but what about $C_p$?

Given any open set $U$ containing $p$  we have that $U\backslash{\{x\}}$ is also open for any $x\neq p$ since the only way $U$ can be open is if we have its complement be finite and adding another point is irrelevant, hence we have that $U\backslash\{x\}\cup\{x\}=U$ is the union of two open sets and therefore can't be connected.

But $\{p\}$ is not open, but then what is $C_p$? Empty?

Comment: Why do you think that $C_p$ has to be open? $C_p=\{p\}$ is correct

Comment: You're right I was thinking along the lines of another exercise and got confused.